# Condition on $X$ in $(0,1)$ with $m=E(X)$ for $\lim\limits_{t\to1}(1-t)E\left[\frac{(X-m)^2}{(m+t(X-m))^2}\right]$ to exist and be finite

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

> Let $X \in (0,1)$ be a continuous random variable.   What would be a sufficient conditions on $X$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{t \to 1}\ (1-t)\, \mathbb E \left[  \frac{(X-\mathbb E[X])^2}{ \left(\mathbb E[X]+t(X-\mathbb E[X]) \right)^2}\right]
> \end{align}
>   is finite.

I tried the monotone convergence theorem but it does not seem to apply. I also spent some time thinking about how to apply dominated convergence theorem.  However, I am not sure how to bound $$(1-t) \frac{(X-\mathbb E[X])^2}{ \left(\mathbb E[X]+t(X-\mathbb E[X]) \right)^2}$$
I have ploted the function
\begin{align}
f(t)= (1-t)\frac{(a-b)^2}{(b+t(a-b))^2}
\end{align}

for $a \in (0,1)$ and $b \in (0,1)$ and it seems to be bounded.  However, not sure how to find and exact bound.

Comment: It would certainly be sufficient (but far from necessary) that $E\left[\frac{(X-E(X))^2}{X^2}\right]$ is finite... then the limit will be zero. (And there are plenty of such distributions... just need the PDF to vanish quickly enough at the origin.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, you are right. But I would really like to exploit properties of $f(t)$ to show that the limit exists. For example, showing that it is bounded.

Comment: It's not immediately apparent to me how that's relevant. Bounded in what sense? The issue is you must bound the expectation value of that expression, which has that divergence in the integral as $a\to 0$ when $t=1.$ I think there are distributions for $X$ for which the limit is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $X$ has continuous distribution with a bounded p.d.f. $f$. Also assume that

$$ f(0^+) := \lim_{x\downarrow 0}f(x) $$

exists. Under this assumption, it is not hard to prove that

> $$ \lim_{t \uparrow 1} \, (1-t) \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{(X - \mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}X + t(X - \mathbb{E}X))^2} \right] = (\mathbb{E}X)  f(0^+). $$

Indeed, let $m = \mathbb{E}X$ for simplicity and write

\begin{align*}
&(1-t) \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{(X - \mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}X + t(X - \mathbb{E}X))^2} \right] \\
&\hspace{1em} = \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)\frac{(x-m)^2}{(m + t(x - m))^2} f(x) \, dx \\
&\hspace{1em} = \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)(x-m)^2 \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} u e^{-(m + t(x - m))u} \, du \right) f(x) \, dx \\
&\hspace{1em} = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-t)m e^{-(1-t)mu} \left( \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{1} u (x-m)^2 e^{-tux} f(x) \, dx \right) \, du.
\end{align*}

By the dominated convergence, it follows that the inner integral converges under the joint limit as $u\uparrow\infty$ and $t \uparrow 1$:

\begin{align*}
I(t,u)
&:= \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{1} u (x-m)^2 e^{-tux} f(x) \, dx \\
&\hspace{2em} = \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{u} \left( \frac{x}{u}-m\right)^2 e^{-tx} f\left(\frac{x}{u}\right) \, dx \\
&\hspace{4em} \xrightarrow[u\uparrow\infty \text{ and } t\uparrow 1]{} \int_{0}^{\infty} m e^{-x} f(0^+) \, dx
= m f(0^+).
\end{align*}

Now by the dominated convergence again,

\begin{align*}
(1-t) \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{(X - \mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}X + t(X - \mathbb{E}X))^2} \right]
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-t)m e^{-(1-t)mu} I(t, u) \, du \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} I\left(t, \frac{u}{(1-t)m}\right) \, du \\
&\xrightarrow[t\uparrow 1]{} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} m f(0^+) \, du
= mf(0^+).
\end{align*}

Comment: Question. Did the arguments of the function $I(t,u)$ got flipped to $I(u,t)$, compared to the definition, in the last few steps?

Comment: @Lisa, You are right, I was sloppy about the order of arguments and now it is fixed.

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is an impressive proof. I learned a lot from it. The most interesting step to me is to introduce an integral in  instead of $\frac{1}{( m+t(x-n))^2}$. How did you think of that?

Comment: @Lisa, Glad it helped. As for the idea, I know that it is often good to write negative powers of a linear polynomial as the gamma integral, since it offer an opportunity to split different terms into a product. Also I got a feeling that your expectation behaves like an approximate delta mass (or concentration of masses), and introducing certain integral transform can sometimes make this behavior clearer and easier to handle with. Luckily this strategy worked for your problem.

Comment: What do you mean that when you said that the expectation behaves alike a delta mass?

Comment: @Lisa, Perhaps my wording is misleading, but please bear with me as my English is still like a baby. Anyway, my intuition was that your function $f(t)$ kind of develops a sharp peak, and I wanted to introduce some tool that can resolve it. Sometimes an appropriate choice of integral transform serves that purpose as we see from my answer.

Comment: In which step is the boundness of pdf important? Is it when we show a result for a joint limit? In there can instead of boundness assume a weaker condition like that Laplace transform exists and is finite.

Comment: @Lisa, It took long to realize that I forgot to answer your comment. As you pointed out, boundedness of $f$ is just a convenient condition introduced to guarantee that dominated convergence is applicable. I am pretty sure that you may replace this by weaker conditions.